# need W10 install-free screen sharing

Tags: collaboration, remote-access, remote-desktop, screen-sharing, remote-control

I want to share my desktop and collaborate with someone outside my org.  Normally I would install teamviewer or anydesk, but that won't work.  My W10 computer is locked down by the infrastructure policy.  I can't install anything.  It has MS Teams, but I can't have meetings with people outside my org.

I found a possible solution in https://deadsimplescreensharing.com/ but from the description It doesn't permit me to give control and let my colleague 'drive.'

Comment: vnc? For example, RealVNC.

Comment: Chrome Remote Desktop is built into Google Chrome https://remotedesktop.google.com

Comment: Neither TeamViewer or AnyDesk require installation, they both have official "portable" versions which don't require any elevated permission. They both still require network access to a proprietary port, though.

Comment: I tried chrome remote desktop and it downloaded an msi, so that is a non starter.  This is the first I've heard of the portable version of teamviewer or anydesk.  So I can just run it from a thumbdrive?  Is that how portable works?